# python 2.7.9-1 is not available

Tags: software-installation, python, debian

I'm trying to run the following command in my Ubuntu 16.04, I cant get the `python 2.7.9-1`, even though its available:

https://packages.debian.org/jessie/python

Any ideas how to fix this?

```
# apt-get install -y curl wget netcat python 2.7.9-1

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package 2.7.9-1
E: Couldn't find any package by glob '2.7.9-1'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex '2.7.9-1'
```

Comment: But Ubuntu 16.04 is not Debian Jessie. I am not sure what you are asking or trying to do.

Comment: @steeldriver It's 2.7.11-1 actually.

Comment: fred@Asusz97:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
fred@Asusz97:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
 But my dpkg says 2.7.11??  fred@Asusz97:~$ dpkg -s python | grep Version
Version: 2.7.11-1

Comment: @oldfred Hmm... same here. You're right, strangely.

Comment: @oldfred Also, `dpkg -s python2.7 | grep Version` gives `Version: 2.7.12-1~16.04`.

Answer (score 3):

The only available `python` version for Ubuntu 16.04 is currently `2.7.11-1`. Your link is for the Debian repositories, the correct site would be http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python

You do not have to specify a version for packages, `apt` automatically chooses the newest available one. Explicit version specifications are only needed when you want to install an older version, and then you would have to separate package name and version string with `=` and not with a space, like `python=2.7.11-1`. Otherwise the version string would be treated as separate package name.

However, `python` is already preinstalled (and required - never attempt to uninstall it!) on all Ubuntu versions, so there would be no need to install it manually again anyway.